# How can I create a simple loop to return a question?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

I am trying to create a loop that asks the user for their age and their zipcode, once it returns their voting station it should loop back and ask again for their age and zipcode. So far my code only asks for the two, returns the station and then finishes.

```
print("VOTER ELIGIBILITY AND POLLING STATION PROGRAM\n\n")
ageMinimum = 18
exitVal = 0
zipCode = 0
zipCodeTemp = 0
age = int(input("Enter your age (Type '0' to exit the program): "))

while age < ageMinimum and age != exitVal:
    print("You are not eligible to vote")
    age = int(input("Enter your age (Type '0' to exit the program): "))

if age == exitVal:
    input("\nRun complete. Press the Enter key to exit.")

if age != exitVal:
    zipCode = int(input("Enter your residence's Zip Code: "))
if age != exitVal and zipCode == ...:
    print("Your polling station is ...")
elif age != exitVal and zipCode == ...:
    print("Your polling station is ...")
elif age != exitVal and zipCode == ...:
    print("Your polling station is ...")
elif age != exitVal and zipCode == ...:
    print(" Your polling station is ...")
elif age != exitVal and zipCode == ...:
    print("Your polling station is ...")
elif zipCode != zipCodeTemp:
    print("Error – unknown zip code")
```

Comment: Replace the if with a while

Comment: So put the whole thing in a `while` loop.

Comment: Replacing it with a while loop continues to ask for the Zip code without asking for the age and not showing the polling station before asking again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix any issue you are having:

```
print("VOTER ELIGIBILITY AND POLLING STATION PROGRAM\n\n")
ageMinimum = 18
exitVal = 0
zipCode = 0
zipCodeTemp = 0
while True:
    age = int(input("Enter your age (Type '0' to exit the program): "))

    while age < ageMinimum and age != exitVal:
        print("You are not eligible to vote")
    if age == exitVal:
        input("\nRun complete. Press the Enter key to exit.")
        exit()
    if age != exitVal:
        zipCode = int(input("Enter your residence's Zip Code: "))
    if age != exitVal and zipCode == ...:
        print("Your polling station is ...")
    elif age != exitVal and zipCode == ...:
        print("Your polling station is ...")
    elif age != exitVal and zipCode == ...:
        print("Your polling station is ...")
    elif age != exitVal and zipCode == ...:
        print(" Your polling station is ...")
    elif age != exitVal and zipCode == ...:
        print("Your polling station is ...")
    elif zipCode != zipCodeTemp:
        print("Error – unknown zip code")
    else:
        print("Some sort of error has occured.")
```